# Why does the length of the elements in the list shrink?

Tags: python

My test code:

```
num = ['a',
       'b',
       'c',
       'd',
       'e'
       'f']
num_len = len(num)
print(num_len)
```

The output is `5`, but I think it should be `6`, why?

Comment: You're missing a comma between `'e'` and `'f'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as what other people have answered, print the list so you can see what Python sees in the list:

```
>>> print(num)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ef']
```

then you can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
num = ['a',
       'b',
       'c',
       'd',
       'e'  //Here should have a comma.
       'f']
num_len = len(num)
print(num_len)
```

Comment: There's the danger of trying to make things look pretty, it can hide what should have been obvious.